# Blender Geometry Nodes Alembic Export misses UVs

Tags: export, nodes, blender, uv-mapping, alembic-format

To put it in a nutshell: In Blender I'm trying to export a geometry nodes animation of a growing root in Alembic format. The problem is, that I can't figure out how to achieve that the UVs of the root mesh are exported.

For context, I'm aware of the general complication within geometry nodes that UVs have to be stored in an attribute and that either that attribute has to be used in the shader editor or that the attribute has to be converted to a UV map. I'm creating mostly static root models and export them for usage in Unreal Engine. My normal workflow is to create a root with geometry nodes based on a bezier curve, generating and storing the UVs in an attribute, converting the bezier curve to a mesh (and thus "baking" the geometry nodes) and finally converting the UV attribute to a proper UV map that shows up in Blenders list of UV maps. I can then export the static mesh as an FBX and everything works fine.

Now I have an animation of a growing root. I'm just keyframing a bunch of parameters in my geometry nodes setup to achieve this. Exporting the animation of the mesh actually just works fine. However, since I can't "bake" the geometry nodes before export (this creates a single mesh with a single frame) I have no opportunity to convert the UV attribute to a UV Map. The Alembic exporter does not seem to recognize the UV attribute and I end up with an animated mesh without any UVs.

I'm pretty stuck on this and would be thankful for any ideas that might help me solving my issue.